# Plugin for event management?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, events, paypal

I have a client who wants to put on an event. She wants to manage it on her site. The requirements:

- Display information about the event
- Sell tickets and correlate with name and email address
- Payment for tickets via PayPal
- Allows for cancellations / returns if they happen
- It may be a recurring event, so allow people to sign up for future events

Anything like that exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is the best I know of:  [Event Calendar / Scheduler](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/event-calendar-scheduler/)

The main features include:

- Day/Week/Month/Year/Agenda view + ability to create custom view
- Drag-n-drop support to configure event date and time
- Customizable appearance
- Single/multi-days events (daily, weekly, monthly or yearly basis)
- Customizable time scale
- Recurring events
- Multilingual

Comment: Does not satisfy all the requirements.
Another good Event Calendar: Events Calendar (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/events-calendar/?compatibility%5Bversion%5D=3.0.1&compatibility%5Btopic_version%5D=6.7.4&compatibility%5Bcompatible%5D=1)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it hits all of your requirements, but the [Advanced Events Registration](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-events-registration/) plugin looks pretty promising.

Answer (score 1):

I'd check out http://shoultes.net/wordpress-events-registration-with-paypal-ipn/ and http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/event-registration/

Answer (score 1):

If you need an event calendar with built in event registration and management fully integrated with WordPress. You should check out the Event Espresso plugin for WordPress. Event Espresso has a built in calendar and features a registration and payment system using PayPal and Authorize.net.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new plugin released:

[WP-SimpleMeetingConfirmation](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-simplemeetingconfirmation/)

Allows registered and/or non registered users to confirm if they will be present at a planned meeting and optionally add comments and number of participants with them.