# The holy grail of Event Management Plugins?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, events

i know [similar](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/207/plugin-for-event-management) [questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11260/can-wordpress-handle-these-functionalities) have been asked before, but the answer's to them don't quite satisfy my needs, so i'm re-iterating the question:

I'm looking for a modern Event Management plugin with the following criteria:

- simple, WP-like UI (Event Calendar 3 is excellent in that regard)
- uses modern WP functionality like custom post types or post meta
- Events are either posts or a custom post type or at least behave like so
- multiple days per Event (can be a single span over several days)
- Registration Management
- clickable Event List or Event Calendar Widget
- ideally, Paypal Integration
- ideally, Email Notification

I've tested a few, but:

- Events Calendar 3 seems to do a lot of things right, but is too basic
- Events Manager Extended looks good, but doesn't seem to work properly with 3.1 (i get neither the map display nor a registration option to show on frontend)
- WP Events Calendar just feels ages old and overwrites my stylesheet on every update
- Event Espresso Lite looks great in terms of functionality, but the Admin Interface is horrible UI

I also tested 'Events' and a few others which were either too simple or had horrible admin interfaces.

Is there anything i haven't seen, yet that i should have a look at?

Comment: Paypal is for money. I’d rather delegate this to a separate plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's really nothing out there that's going to solve all of your problems out of the box.  Whatever calender solution you choose will require some amount of customization.

The one that I've found fills *most* needs is [The Events Calendar](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/the-events-calendar/).  It's not perfect, but it's a lot better than many other events calendar plugins out there.  Trust me, I've tried them all.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Events Calendar Pro](http://codecanyon.net/item/events-calendar-pro-wordpress-premium-plugin/109301) for a project, and have been happy with the results. It uses a custom post type for the events data, and offers a couple of different views for the data (calendar and list).

It's not free, but I thought its additional functionality was worth the nominal cost.

Comment: I think i went with the free version of that plugin in the end, which is called The Events Calendar. It is pretty well done, doesn't use a custom post type, but uses metadata on posts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve, but this may be worth looking at:

http://gigpress.com

It's designed for musicians and seems very well built out. Could be useful?